# Is there an easy way to tell what decisions I made in a Witcher 2 save game?

Tags: the-witcher-series

So I'm ready to play Witcher 3 and I have many save games from Witcher 2, but I can't remember which is which! I re-played so many parts to try the different paths.

I picked one at random and Geralt has a tattoo on his neck (I'd forgotten about that), but what else happened in that save? Who died? What's the political balance in the land? Iorveth or Roche?

Reinstalling Witcher 2 to check them out might be the go, but does anyone know if there are any other options? Wish Witcher 3 had given me a recap of those decisions when I was choosing which save file ~:)

Comment: That tatoo appears if you side with Roche, got drunk with his men and woke up naked at the beach. ;p

Comment: @YUNOWORK only if you did not remove said tattoo later in witcher 2.

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith Well he just asked where this came from, i just told him.^^

Comment: I went with the tattoo save and it was great. Nobody commented on the tattoo unfortunately, that would have been funny. My advice to anyone reading this is: don't overthink it, just go play!

Answer (score 3):

If you read the description (or journal text that Dandelion wrote) next to quests that you've completed, it summarizes any decisions you made.

[This page](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/The_Witcher_2_decision_checklist) gives a good list of all of the big decisions in the game. It doesn't list minor stuff like the tattoo, however.